# list not printing into file

Tags: java, printing, doubly-linked-list

I am having trouble with my printer. It does not write to my file as it returns a null and the loop does not finish. My loop goes through the sorting but at the end gives a null. Thank you.
[My code is here.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d4950c45e3fc669f6d18)

My input file is:

one

two

three

four

five

output file should be:

five

four

one

three

two

Comment: Can you please try debug (or learn how to) your code..

Comment: Try inserting a few breakpoints, and then checking the local variables to see what is happening. Once you find out specific problems, you can add details on them so that we can try to help.

Comment: <code>
for(l.moveTo(0); l.getIndex() >= 0; l.moveNext())
{   
  outFile.println(stringArray[l.getElement()]);
  System.out.println("arr: " + stringArray[l.getElement()]);
  System.out.println("index : " + l.getIndex());
  System.out.println("element : " + l.getElement());

} </code>

Answer (score 0):

```
for(l.moveTo(0); l.getIndex() >= 0; l.moveNext())
{           
  outFile.println(stringArray[l.getElement()]);
  System.out.println("arr: " + stringArray[l.getElement()]);
  System.out.println("index : " + l.getIndex());
  System.out.println("element : " + l.getElement());

}
```

Through the whole loop it gives me :(

```
index = 0 
l.length = 3
```

I added some lines to check. It is my index or getElement that is giving me trouble.

while this does not print in order

```
  for (String current : stringArray)
    {
        outFile.println(current);
    }
    outFile.close();
```

I would make it this but will also give a null problem.

```
  for (String current : stringArray)
    {
        outFile.println(stringArray[l.getElement()]);
    }
    outFile.close();
```